# OpenGL VAO Index Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: opengl, c++, index-buffer, vao

I'm going insane trying to work out why I unable to draw a triangle using VAO and indexing. I have a bunch of redundant vertexes so that i can switch my index array up to test the drawing.

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;

//bot left
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.75,0.9,1));     //0
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.5, 0.9, 1));    //1
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.25, 0.9, 1));   //2
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.0, 0.9, 1));    //3
//mid right
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.75, 0, 1));  //4 
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.5, 0, 1));   //5
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.25, 0, 1));  //6
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0.0, 0, 1));   //7
//top left
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.75, -0.9, 1));  //8
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.9, 1));   //9
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.25, -0.9, 1));  //10
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-0.0, -0.9, -1));  //11
```

The indices are simple:

```
 GLuint indices[] = {0,5,11};
```

Here is how I am initialising everything:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &ivbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
    &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,sizeof(glm::vec3), (void*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ivbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I am rendering with:

```
glUseProgram(program);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);//clear red

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

glutSwapBuffers();
```

Vertex shader is simple as they come:

```
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1);
}
```

Same with the fragment shader

```
#version 430 core
out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
  color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

EDIT: Switching the z coordinate in the vertices to a negative value fixes the problem. What is going on?

Comment: Do you have backface culling on?

Comment: Well if it was before it is not now. Unfortunately it has not fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you fix sizeof(indices)? Also in bytes.

Comment: sizeof(indices) is now `sizeof(GLuint)*indiciesSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to ensure all vertices are rendered:

- Ensure that backface culling is disabled with `GlDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`
- Disable depth testing `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` OR ensure you are clearing the depth buffer bit before drawing `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`

---

Second

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),&vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

is incorrect.

Second parameter to glBufferData is size of vertex array in bytes. Passing `sizeof(vertices)` will pass the 24 bytes (32 on debug) that indicate the pointer to the start location of the vector and the end location of the vector.

Instead you should use:

```
sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size()
```

The same thing happens with the size you pass size to the ELEMENTS_BUFFER .

---

glBufferData's second argument is the size in **Bytes** of the array you are passing. 
When it say's size in Bytes it means the whole size of *your* **vertices** vector.

So in this specific scenario you have stored 12 positions. Every one of those elements is a float number as we can see and every position consists of three float numbers.

"Coding" this would be

```
sizeof(float) * 3 * vertices.size();
```

- Normally sizeof(float) will return 4 which are the bytes for a float-number.
- vertices.size() will return 12 since you have 12 positions stored.
- and 3 is just a constant indicating that for every position you have 3 float-numbers.

So the size in bytes that you will have to pass as an argument to glBufferData is 4 * 3 * 12 = **144Bytes**.

You need to do the same for the Elements buffer.

Comment: Hmmm... Nope. Not even the first triangle draws now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `sizeof(std::vector<...>)` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Yes you are right, i tried to give a quick one but as a said i am in a bit of hurry. I tried to give an example of what size should look like, your glBufferData size parameter is wrong anyways fix it and i think your problem should go away/..

Comment: `sizeof(std::vector<glm::vec3>) * vertices.size()` should work but it doesnt... `sizeof(std::vector<glm::vec3>)' returns 12 bytes as it should. Weirdly `sizeof (vertices)` returns less bytes than `sizeof(std::vector<glm::vec3>) * vertices.size()`. Getting nothing being drawn.

Comment: I am editing my answer, to cover your question.